Form validation for required fields on Submit in Angular 17
I have many fields like firstName, lastName, etc which is made required from the backend. If I submit the form without filling up the firstName, it throws the following error in the Network Preview. If I fill up firstName and leave lastName empty, it will throw another error: lastName is required in the Network Preview:
{
    "status": "failed",
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid request data. Please review the request and try again.",
        "code": [
            {
                "message": "firstName is required",
                "code": "any.required"
            }
        ]
    }
}

HTML:
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="registration.firstName">
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="registration.lastName">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="createRegistration(registration)">Submit</button>

I simply want to throw the error message as shown in the Network Preview when someone try to click Submit button somewhere on the page:
<p>firstName is required</p>

TS:
createRegistration(registration:StudentRegistration){
    this.coreService.addRegistration(registration).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.registration = res.data || {} as StudentRegistration;
        this.opd.registration = res.data._id;
        this.createOpdStudent()
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })
  }

I have seen a lot of frontend-validation tutorials in Angular but that's just too much effort as I have to validate every field again in the frontend. I can't find any backend validation tutorial like in my case.
PS: Working frontend method I don't want to use as there are multiple forms with 100s of fields
<p *ngIf="registration.firstName == '' || registration.firstName == undefined">First name is compulsory</p>


So you are looking for display the error message from the response in the view?

@YongShun Yes. Basically that message.

@YongShun or at least a way to detect the error message so i can apply [ngClass] on the <div> where firstName is.

In the error callback, you can extract the error message as below:
errorMessages: string[] = [];

error: (err) => {
  console.log(err);

  let errorResponse = err.error;
  this.errorMessages = errorResponse.code.map((x: any) => x.message);
}

To display set of errorMessages:
<div *ngFor="let errorMessage of errorMessages">
  {{ errorMessage }}
</div>

If you are looking to display the error messages by section field, you should need the implementation to check and get the error message by field name:
<div [ngClass]="{'show': hasError('firstName'), 'hide': !hasError('firstName')}">
  <span>FirstName error</span>
  <div *ngFor="let errorMessage of getErrorsByField('firstName')">
    {{ errorMessage }}
  </div>
</div>

hasError(fieldName: string) {
  return this.errorMessages.some((x) => x.indexOf(fieldName) > -1);
}

getErrorsByField(fieldName: string) {
  return this.errorMessages.filter((x) => x.indexOf(fieldName) > -1);
}

Demo @ StackBlitz
